# How to prevent unauthorized user to access the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, web-applications, web, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to prevent unauthorized user to access the web based application. My application is developed in RoR. It is a rich internet application.
   and one more thing similarly also do for when no of user limit is exided. for that please suggest me the way...by desktop serial no/ mac no/ user email-id or any other your way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you make them "login" don't you, and then you authorise. 
How the client identifies itself if username / password isn't what you want is up to you, as long as it's effective.

Masses of ways of doing that, Authlogic and CanCan gems for instance.